# How to check if parentheses are balanced in given array?

Tags: java

Is there some way of doing this without using `Stack`:

`()`  should return  TRUE (balanced)

`(()` should return FALSE (Unbalanced)

```
public static boolean check(String s) {
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
        counter++;
    } else if (s.charAt(i) == ')') {
        if (counter == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        counter--;
    }
}
return counter == 0;
}
```

Comment: why have you asked the question while providing code that answers the question already, in the question itself?

Comment: I guess you have some trouble as it looks like your code will work for something like '())(' while it should be reported as an error. Please, rewrite your question to clarify your problem and more than probably somebody will find an answer. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

First remove anything other than `"("` and `")"` from the string with

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^\\(\\)]", "");
```

then in a loop remove gradually all occurrences of `"()"`. 
If this results to an empty string then return `true`.

```
public static boolean check(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("[^\\(\\)]", "");
    while (s.contains("()")) {
        s = s.replace("()", "");
    }
    return s.isEmpty();
}
```